# How to get Controller Assignments working with the Recorder part of Quick Sampler in Logic Pro 10.5?

Tags: midi, daw, logic-pro

I'm running into a weird bug/issue when mapping the record feature within Logic Pro 10.5's new quick sampler to a button on my midi controller:

I mapped the Record button to a button on my midi controller using Learn Mode in controller assignments as follows (the midi button on my keyboard is 90 5F and learned mode maps the record click in quick sampler to Quick Sampler #375: 
[image]

when I hit that button on my midi controller the quick sampler recorder changes visually to appear to be recording but isn't actually recording any input (I tried this both in Threshold mode, with audio that was above the threshold and in immediately begin recording mode):
[image: appears to be recording but doesn't actually record anything]

When I trigger recording in quick sampler via a mouse click, the UI similarly changes, but additional text stating "Waiting for the input signal to exceed the threshold" shows up and recording succeeds when the audio is above the threshold:

[image: note the text of "Waiting for the input signal to exceed the threshold" the occurs when you click the button vs use a controller assignment as shown in the previous figure]

Being able to map recording into quick sampler to a midi button would be a huge game changer, so if this is possible, I'd love to know how!